# Remove from superview AND enable user interaction

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewanimation

I'm doing some custom animations to change views in a single method. I already removed "fromView" from superView using `[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)]`, but I also want to enable user interaction after the end of the animation.

Here's my code:

```
-(void) switchFrom:(UIViewController*) fromViewController To:(UIViewController*) toViewController usingAnimation:(int) animation{
    UIView *fromView = fromViewController.view;
    UIView *toView = toViewController.view;
    /*************** SET ALL DEFAULT TRANSITION SETTINGS ***************/
    // Get the current view frame, width and height
    CGRect pageFrame = fromView.frame;
    CGFloat pageWidth = pageFrame.size.width;
    
    // Create the animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    
    // Create the delegate, so the "fromView" is removed after the transition
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate: fromView];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    
    // Set the transition duration
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.4];

    /*************** IT DOESN'T WORK AT ALL ***************/
    [toView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate: toView];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(setUserInteractionEnabled:)];
    [toView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    // Add the "toView" as subview of "fromView" superview
    [fromView.superview addSubview:toView];
    switch (animation) {
        case AnimationPushFromRigh:{
            // Position the "toView" to the right corner of the page            
            toView.frame = CGRectOffset(pageFrame, pageWidth,0);
            
            // Animate the "fromView" to the left corner of the page
            fromView.frame = CGRectOffset(pageFrame, -pageWidth,0);
            
            // Animate the "toView" to the center of the page
            toView.frame = pageFrame;
            
            // Animate the "fromView" alpha
            fromView.alpha = 0;
            
            // Set and animate the "toView" alpha
            toView.alpha = 0;
            toView.alpha = 1;

            // Commit the animation
            [UIView commitAnimations];
        }
        .
        .
        .
```

Any idea how can I call this two methods in `setAnimationDidStopSelector` and actually make them work together?

## EDIT 1

Tried @safecase code like this, replacing this commented block:

```
/*************** IT DOESN'T WORK AT ALL ***************
[toView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate: toView];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(setUserInteractionEnabled:)];
[toView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
*************** IT DOESN'T WORK AT ALL ***************/
// Remove the interaction
[toView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[fromView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
// Create the animation
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
    [fromView performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 
        animations:^{ 
            C6Log(@"finished");
            [toView performSelector: @selector(setUserInteractionEnabled:)];
        }];
    }];
```

The "toView" is removed instead of the "fromView" is removed :(
The buttons continue to be interactive during the animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a Category extension to UIView… and it finally works!

**UIView+Animated.h code**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (Animated)

- (void) finishedAnimation;

@end
```

**UIView+Animated.m code**

```
#import "UIView+Animated.h"

@implementation UIView (Animated)

- (void) finishedAnimation{
    C6Log(@"FinishedAnimation!");
    [self removeFromSuperview];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
}

@end
```

Then, I #imported this extension in my coordinating controller:

**C6CoordinatingController.h partial code**

```
#import "UIView+Animated.h"
```

And called the selector in setAnimationDidStopSelector:

**C6CoordinatingController.m partial code**

```
// Create the delegate, so the "fromView" is removed after the transition
[UIView setAnimationDelegate: fromView];

// Ignore interaction events during the animation
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];

// Set the transition duration
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.4];

// Call UIView+Animated "finishedAnimation" method when animation stops
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(finishedAnimation)];
```

So, I ended up using @jaydee3 and @Mundi concepts and it works like a charm!

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

Do you know `beginIgnoringInteractionEvents` and `endIgnoringInteractionEvents`?
Normally, if you don't want any userInteraction during an animation, you would use those.

Anyway you still need correct callbacks to trigger them.

Comment: Nope… I'll check it out to see how to use this instead of "makeInteractionEnabled".

Comment: It also works fine… but I still can't perform both "remove fromView" and "endIgnoringInteractionEvents" together…

I'll try creating a method (like @Mundi suggested) removing the "fromView" and calling "endIgnoringInteractionEvents".

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your own method, e.g. `remove:` and pass that as the selector. In the method, just use the passed `UIView` to remove it.

```
-(void)remove:(id)sender {
   UIView *v = (UIView*)sender;
   [v removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: But I need two "senders"… toView (to remove from superView) and fromView (to enable interactions).

Can I set two distinct "setAnimationDidStopSelector"? Will it work?

Comment: Isn't the "from view" the original superview? If so, why not using that relationship in the method drafted above?

Comment: @Till, actually, there is a "mainView" superview… I could try something like this…

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4

 animations:^{ [self performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)]; // other code here}

 completion:^(BOOL finished){ [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4

 animations:^{ [self performSelector:@selector(setUserInteractionEnabled:)]; //other code here}]; }];
```

Hope helpful.

Comment: Somehow, this code does not work… but it really seems to be in the right path… I'll do some tests with it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use to enable user interaction
self.view.userInteractionEnabled=NO;

Comment: I did this… but I need it to be reenabled after the animation.